# Does Glass.Mapper.Sc uses index fields for a sitecore7 search

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I my project I am using Sitecore7 MVC, Solr and Glass Mapper.

The "ContentSearch" index contains pretty much all the fields used in sitecore template.
I am using GlassMapper classes as my Models (which contains pretty much nothing but properties that are sitecore fields) and querying on it. Basically doing "Using A Custom Result Class" as described here : http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial25/tutorial25.html

Which works as it is supposed to.

**My question is:**

Is it populating the class properties ( which are typically sitecore fields ) using Solr index as long as the index exists (which is what I want) ?

**OR**

Is it going to sitecore to get the Field Values ? (which I would think is inefficient and in which case I will write custom classes and loop over them to populate glassMapper classes because in my views I have used GlassMapper classes as my models)

For example one of my Models looks like this:

```
    [SitecoreType]
    public class MyAwesomeModel
    {
        [SitecoreId]
        [IndexField("_id")]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Language)]
        [IndexField("_language")]
        public virtual string Language { get; set; }

        [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter))]
        [XmlIgnore]
        [IndexField("_uniqueid")]
        public virtual ItemUri Uri { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Version)]
        public virtual int Version
        {
            get
            {
                return Uri == null ? 0 : Uri.Version.Number;
            }
        }

        [SitecoreField(FieldName="MyRichtextField")]
        [IndexField("MyRichtextField")]
        public virtual string RichTextContent { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Url, UrlOptions = SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.LanguageEmbeddingNever)]
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually just pushed some code to my Fork of Glass.Mapper that does right that:
https://github.com/csteeg/Glass.Mapper (in the develop branch)

You have to patch your config, so you'll use glass specific contentsearch settings:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper>
            <objectFactory type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapperObjectFactory, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <patch:attribute name="type">Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.GlassDocumentMapperObjectFactory, Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider</patch:attribute>
            </objectFactory>
          </indexDocumentPropertyMapper>
        </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="sitecore_master_index">
            <patch:attribute name="type">Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.GlassLuceneIndex, Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider</patch:attribute>
          </index>
          <index id="sitecore_web_index">
            <patch:attribute name="type">Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.GlassLuceneIndex, Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider</patch:attribute>
          </index>
          <index id="sitecore_core_index">
            <patch:attribute name="type">Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.GlassLuceneIndex, Glass.Mapper.Sc.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider</patch:attribute>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The code first returns values from the index, if they are stored there. If a property is requested that is not stored in the index, it will get the value from the Sitecore item